# Can't Read from and write to kafka topic using spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I am writing a sample spark streaming program to read the messages from input kafka topic and write it to console and another output kafka topic. Not getting any error or exception, but I am not seeing messages in console as well as in output kafka topic too. Can anyone please let me know where/what am I missing.

This is my code.

```
    object Test extends App {
      val logger: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Test.getClass)
      val kafkalogger = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("kafka")
      kafkalogger.info("Running Pipeline")
      kafkalogger.setLevel(Level.INFO);
      val spark = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
      
      val dfStream = spark.readStream
          .format("kafka")
          .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "*.*.*.*:9092")
          .option("subscribe", "input-topic")
          .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
          .load()
    
        dfStream.printSchema()
    
        val messageDF = dfStream.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
        
        messageDF.printSchema()
        
        kafkalogger.info("Before writing messages to console")
        
        messageDF.writeStream.outputMode("append").format("console").start()
        
        kafkalogger.info("After writing to console")
         val writeToKafka = dfStream
          //.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
         .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
          .writeStream
          .format("kafka")
          .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "*.*.*.*:9092")
          .option("topic", "output-topic")
          .option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/jsp_checkpointdir")
          .start()
        kafkalogger.info("After writing to topic")
        writeToKafka.awaitTermination()
    }
```

I am able to see the schema of dataframe, but not the actual messages.

```
21/11/08 07:02:00 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@2b99c937{/static/sql,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
root
 |-- key: binary (nullable = true)
 |-- value: binary (nullable = true)
 |-- topic: string (nullable = true)
 |-- partition: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- offset: long (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- timestampType: integer (nullable = true)

root
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)

21/11/08 07:02:03 INFO kafka: Before writing messages to console
21/11/08 07:02:03 INFO ResourceProfile: Default ResourceProfile created, executor resources: Map(memoryOverhead -> name: memoryOverhead, amount: 512, script: , vendor: , cores -> name: cores, amount: 2, script: , vendor: , memory -> name: memory, amount: 4096, script: , vendor: ), task resources: Map(cpus -> name: cpus, amount: 1.0)
21/11/08 07:02:03 INFO StateStoreCoordinatorRef: Registered StateStoreCoordinator endpoint
21/11/08 07:02:03 INFO ServerInfo: Adding filter to /StreamingQuery: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter
21/11/08 07:02:03 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@40fd1a78{/StreamingQuery,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
21/11/08 07:02:03 INFO ServerInfo: Adding filter to /StreamingQuery/json: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter
21/11/08 07:02:03 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@32430075{/StreamingQuery/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
21/11/08 07:02:03 INFO ServerInfo: Adding filter to /StreamingQuery/statistics: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter
21/11/08 07:02:03 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@60f1f95b{/StreamingQuery/statistics,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
21/11/08 07:02:03 INFO ServerInfo: Adding filter to /StreamingQuery/statistics/json: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter
21/11/08 07:02:03 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@6f926d01{/StreamingQuery/statistics/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
21/11/08 07:02:03 INFO ServerInfo: Adding filter to /static/sql: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter
21/11/08 07:02:03 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@10e4ce98{/static/sql,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
21/11/08 07:02:03 WARN StreamingQueryManager: Temporary checkpoint location created which is deleted normally when the query didn't fail: /mnt/tmp/temporary-666cc7f1-7209-411d-b550-bc9b9e2ed79f. If it's required to delete it under any circumstances, please set spark.sql.streaming.forceDeleteTempCheckpointLocation to true. Important to know deleting temp checkpoint folder is best effort.
21/11/08 07:02:03 WARN StreamingQueryManager: spark.sql.adaptive.enabled is not supported in streaming DataFrames/Datasets and will be disabled.
21/11/08 07:02:03 INFO MicroBatchExecution: Checkpoint root /mnt/tmp/temporary-666cc7f1-7209-411d-b550-bc9b9e2ed79f resolved to hdfs://ip-10-0-2-229.ap-south-1.compute.internal:8020/mnt/tmp/temporary-666cc7f1-7209-411d-b550-bc9b9e2ed79f.
21/11/08 07:02:03 INFO CheckpointFileManager: Writing atomically to hdfs://ip-10-0-2-229.ap-south-1.compute.internal:8020/mnt/tmp/temporary-666cc7f1-7209-411d-b550-bc9b9e2ed79f/metadata using temp file hdfs://ip-10-0-2-229.ap-south-1.compute.internal:8020/mnt/tmp/temporary-666cc7f1-7209-411d-b550-bc9b9e2ed79f/.metadata.2a9256a4-a174-4ebb-b671-a1f011b78158.tmp
21/11/08 07:02:03 INFO CheckpointFileManager: Renamed temp file hdfs://ip-10-0-2-229.ap-south-1.compute.internal:8020/mnt/tmp/temporary-666cc7f1-7209-411d-b550-bc9b9e2ed79f/.metadata.2a9256a4-a174-4ebb-b671-a1f011b78158.tmp to hdfs://ip-10-0-2-229.ap-south-1.compute.internal:8020/mnt/tmp/temporary-666cc7f1-7209-411d-b550-bc9b9e2ed79f/metadata
21/11/08 07:02:03 INFO MicroBatchExecution: Starting [id = 3393cbc3-9899-4053-8cb6-8c7654d8db28, runId = 23729550-4fc3-4500-8fcf-fa76da0ed3cf]. Use hdfs://ip-10-0-2-229.ap-south-1.compute.internal:8020/mnt/tmp/temporary-666cc7f1-7209-411d-b550-bc9b9e2ed79f to store the query checkpoint.
21/11/08 07:02:03 INFO kafka: After writing to console
21/11/08 07:02:03 WARN StreamingQueryManager: spark.sql.adaptive.enabled is not supported in streaming DataFrames/Datasets and will be disabled.
21/11/08 07:02:03 INFO MicroBatchExecution: Checkpoint root /tmp/jsp_checkpointdir resolved to hdfs://ip-10-0-2-229.ap-south-1.compute.internal:8020/tmp/jsp_checkpointdir.
21/11/08 07:02:03 INFO MicroBatchExecution: Reading table [org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider$KafkaTable@43309170] from DataSourceV2 named 'kafka' [org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider@d19db03]
21/11/08 07:02:03 INFO MicroBatchExecution: Starting new streaming query.
21/11/08 07:02:03 INFO MicroBatchExecution: Stream started from {}
21/11/08 07:02:03 INFO MicroBatchExecution: Starting [id = 3ae88b1d-c4bb-4a7c-be5c-4a75fda4903d, runId = 0d089f20-c110-465b-add9-080e213dd72d]. Use hdfs://ip-10-0-2-229.ap-south-1.compute.internal:8020/tmp/jsp_checkpointdir to store the query checkpoint.
21/11/08 07:02:03 INFO kafka: After writing to topic
21/11/08 07:02:03 INFO MicroBatchExecution: Reading table [org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider$KafkaTable@43309170] from DataSourceV2 named 'kafka' [org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider@d19db03]
21/11/08 07:02:03 INFO MicroBatchExecution: Starting new streaming query.
21/11/08 07:02:03 INFO MicroBatchExecution: Stream started from {}
21/11/08 07:02:03 INFO ConsumerConfig: ConsumerConfig values:
        allow.auto.create.topics = true
        auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
        auto.offset.reset = earliest
```

These are the messages in input kafka topic

```
[root@ip-*.*.*.* kafka]# bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic input-topic --from-beginning
test message
message2
message3
message4
message4
message5
message6
```

No messages in output-topic too.

```
[root@ip-*.*.*.* kafka]# bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic output-topic --from-beginning
```

Comment: If your goal is simply to read and write to the same cluster, you should just use Kafka Streams

Comment: Hi OneCricketeer, already we are using spark, so going with spark streaming.

Comment: But you're also deploying Java/Scala applications in other places, I assume, so why not use it?

Comment: Connection issue resolved, I was using localhost in listeners in server.properties file instead of IP. But, still actual issue remains. I can't see messages on console as well as in output-topic.

Comment: You should use `0.0.0.0` as `listeners` rather than any specific IP

Comment: Tried by setting listeners as 0.0.0.0, but still can't see messages.

Comment: I suggest you remove the `writeStream.format("kafka")` code until you have `.format("console")` working. Also, why aren't you using `messageDF` for the output topic?

Comment: Removed writeStream.format("kafka"), still no use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is resolved after reverting the configuration changes to config/server.properties file and kept it as default config. I'm unable to consume from the beginning of the topic if messages entered the topic before Spark streaming job is started. This is different issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess you have some network issues to figure out, but the following works for me locally (tested with Spark 2.4.8).

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.OffsetResetStrategy
import org.apache.spark.sql
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.OutputMode
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

object KafkaTest extends App {

  val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass)

  /**
   * For testing output to a console.
   *
   * @param df A Streaming DataFrame
   * @return A DataStreamWriter
   */
  private def streamToConsole(df: sql.DataFrame) = {
    df.writeStream.outputMode(OutputMode.Append()).format("console")
  }

  private def getKafkaDf(spark: SparkSession, bootstrap: String, topicPattern: String, offsetResetStrategy: OffsetResetStrategy = OffsetResetStrategy.EARLIEST) = {
    spark.readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", bootstrap)
      .option("subscribe", topicPattern)
      .option("startingOffsets", offsetResetStrategy.toString.toLowerCase())
      .load()
  }

  private def streamToKafka(df: sql.DataFrame, bootstrap: String, checkpointLocation: String) = {
    val cols = df.columns
    if (!cols.contains("topic")) {
      val e = new IllegalArgumentException(s"""Dataframe columns must contain 'topic'. Existing cols=[${cols.mkString(", ")}]""")
      logger.error("Unable to stream dataframe to Kafka", e)
      throw e
    }
    // output topic comes from dataframe, not from options
    df.writeStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", bootstrap)
      .option("checkpointLocation", checkpointLocation) // required option
  }

  val spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .appName("Kafka Test")
    .master("local[*]")
    .getOrCreate()
  import spark.implicits._
  
  val kafkaBootstrap = "localhost:9092"

  val df = getKafkaDf(spark, kafkaBootstrap, "input-topic")
  streamToKafka(
    // Stream topic values into the same partition from input-topic to output-topic
    df.select($"partition", $"value", regexp_replace($"topic", "^input", "output").as("topic")),
    kafkaBootstrap,
    checkpointLocation = "/tmp/spark-sql-kafka"
  ).start().awaitTermination()
}
```

Comment: Thanks OneCricketeer for your reply. But, my case spark and kafka are running on two different EC2 instances. I am able to ping/telnet kafka publicIP/hostname from EMR edge node.

Comment: As they should be. Like I said, you've got a network issue then. Technically, my Kafka broker is in a different network (Docker), but it was port forwarded. If Spark cannot read/write, then neither should the Kafka CLI tools from the EC2 Spark/YARN nodes